# How to query only the labels for custom or standard objects

Tags: soql, dynamic-soql

`SELECT Fields(standard) FROM Contact`
This queries all the records of all the fields in the Contact object, but I want to query only the **labels of the fields** so that I can create a picklist of all the fields of the Contact object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Apex [Schema](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_schema.htm#apex_System_Schema_getGlobalDescribe) class to do a `GlobalDescribe` on the chosen SObject and then work your way through the `fieldMap` to retrieve each label.

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Contact').getDescribe().fields.getMap();
List<String> labels = new List<String>();
for (String fieldName: fieldMap.keySet()) {
    labels.add(fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getLabel());
}
```

If you wish to only add labels for standard fields, you can use the `isCustom` method on [DescribeFieldResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeFieldResult_isCustom).

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Contact').getDescribe().fields.getMap();
List<String> labels = new List<String>();
for (String fieldName: fieldMap.keySet()) {
    DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe();
    Boolean isCustom = fieldResult.isCustom();
    // Standard fields only
    if (!isCustom) labels.add(fieldResult.getLabel());
}
```